# Replacement for subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdate

Tags: swift, core-telephony

I want to detect when a user changes the SIM card.
I tried using subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdate but after removing and reinserting the SIM card the closure/block never gets called. Also the instance property is deprecated.  Is there a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

`subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier` appears to have been replaced with `serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier` as of iOS 12.

If you need to support iOS 11 or earlier in addition to iOS 12 you can something like:

```
let ct = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    ct.serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier = { (carrier) in
        // carrier is a String
    }
} else {
    ct.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = { (carrier) in
        // carrier is a CTCarrier
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this between op and your answer.  However neither is getting called when I simply remove and reinsert same sim.   Going to try with new different sim and will update....waiting to get another sim

Comment: Make sure you are keeping a strong reference to the `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` instance.

Comment: It is a constant property of AppDelegate and I have verified that on iOS 12 neither block for serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersDidUpdateNotifier or  subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier is getting called when switching sim cards.

Comment: This block is only getting called when you swap the sim card to another **“provider”**. For example, swapping from T-Mobile to AT&T causes an invocation.